# randomly generated users in mysql?

Tags: mysql

is this a thing that happens? in a mysql database for a client I do `select user();` and I get: `cpses_klFbjdlacB` and then a week later I do the same command and get `cpses_klFbjdlacV` Is this a mysql thing?

Comment: Is what a MySQL thing? Giving you info about currently logged user? Yes, it is. If you're asking why the two are different - because someone changed something or because you connected using different credentials. We can't know because we lack information.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with leftover user sessions in Cpanel. There is a discussion about it here:
http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/weird-cpses-error-messages-376762.html